# what Vector3. I would use here in transform.rotate

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: rotate]

I want to rotate my player in the way I showed in the picture. I don't understand what Vector3. I would use here in transform.rotate

Comment: Sorry, but just want to make sure that i'm getting it right. So What you are asking What Vector3 is right?

Comment: I guess that I have an answer for your question but I just want to confirm that what i understood is what you are asking.

Comment: yeah, Vector3.up, right are working (because they are not the direction I want), I think there should be a type of rotation for that

Comment: try using ```Vector3.forward``` This should work

Comment: I'm Adding an answer explaining why this is working, so that you and other can understand.

Answer (score 2):

As we talked in comments I guess that you know what Vectors are from your background.
And with `transform.rotate()` there are more then one options to use that method which we call [Method Overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-method-overloading/). And one of the way to use is that is `transform.Rotate(Vector3 direction, float rotation)`.

And the reason it takes `Vector3` as a direction in this method is because the way Unity handles direction.

In Unity as when it comes to direction with `Vector3` it is considered/calculated as follows

```
Vector3.right   = x = 1,  y = 0,  z = 0
Vector3.left    = x = -1, y = 0,  z = 0
Vector3.up      = x = 0,  y = 1,  z = 0
Vector3.down    = x = 0,  y = -1, z = 0
Vector3.forward = x = 0,  y = 0,  z = 1
Vector3.back    = x = 0,  y = 0,  z = -1
```

So to answering your question you can achieve the functionality by using `Vector3.forword` as direction. Because the direction/Axis you want your object to be rotated is the one from `back` to `front` if you consider `Vector3` that would be z axis ans as I've listed above you can use `Vector3.forward` as a direction/axis of your rotation in `transform.Rotate()`

Reference:
[Tranform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

Hope this helps, welcome to unity `Happy Coding`

Comment: Helpful info but you should probably include your comment's "`Vector3.forward`" in the answer somewhere ;)