# Rotate Object Smooth 90 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

God morning! I want to rotate an object smooth 90 degrees in an if statement. I've looked and searched for the solution everywhere but i couldn't find any fitting solution for my needs. This is what i want it to look like:

```cs
if (Swipe.Left)
{ 
    Object smooth rotate 90 degrees down //left
}
```

I hope someone knows how i could do this! I'm thankful for any help :)

EDIT : I've tried this before but it seems like it does not work with if statements:

```cs
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.down);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, .03f);
```

Comment: what is `Swipe`?

Comment: @Bizhan Hey! That's a controller that looks if the player swipes with his finger. And in which direction. Did i answer your question? :)

Comment: so it returns true during one frame, right?

Comment: @Bizhan that's right.

Comment: What about transform.Rotate(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Space.Self);

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Swipe.Left` returns true during only one frame you have to sustain the logic for a longer period. To do that let's enable a flag on swipe and disable the flag when the target rotation is reached.

```
if (Swipe.Left)
{ 
     swiped = true;
     newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.down);
     slerpEase = .03f;
}

if (swiped)
{ 
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, slerpEase);
    slerpEase *= 0.95f;
    if (Mathf.Approximately(1f, Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, newRotation)))
        swiped = false; // reached the target rotation
}
```

Also notice that I used a variable named `slerpEase` to smoothly slow down the rotation as the object rotates over time. You may want to change `0.95f` to make it dependent on delta time.

Note that, if you rotate it around two axis, comparing angles will be a bit tricky due to Gimbal lock.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try this, what is slerpEase?

Comment: @StarRocket it's a float. (though I should've called it ease-in) the term "ease" is a general animation term meaning how fast do you want to leave the starting state (ease-out) or to reach the target state (ease-in).

Comment: okay, looks fine. Now i only need to fix the `transform.rotation.EulerAngles.z - newRotation.EulerAngles.z` part. Lets see if i find something about it in the Unity documentations.

Comment: Consider using `if (Mathf.Approximately(1f, Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, targetRotation)))` instead of `if(Mathf.Abs(transform.rotation.EulerAngles.z - newRotation.EulerAngles.z) < 0.001f)`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a coroutine for this, with an [AnimationCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) to determine the smoothness of the turn. This will let you fine tune the appearance you want just using the inspector, and it allows for nice code re-use if you want different degrees.

```
[SerializeField] private AnimationCurve swipeRotateAnimationCurve; // configure in inspector
private Coroutine swipeRotateCoroutine = null;
private float swipeRotationDuration = 2f; // duration of rotation in seconds

// ...

if (Swipe.Left)
{ 
    // Cancel any currently running coroutine
    if (swipeRotateCoroutine != null) 
    {
        StopCoroutine(swipeRotateCoroutine);
        swipeRotateCoroutine = null;
    }

    swipeRotateCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DoHorizontalSwipeRotate(-90f));
}
else if (Swipe.Right)
{ 
    // Cancel any currently running coroutine
    if (swipeRotateCoroutine != null) 
    {
        StopCoroutine(swipeRotateCoroutine);
        swipeRotateCoroutine = null;
    }

    swipeRotateCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DoHorizontalSwipeRotate(90f));  
}

// ...

private IEnumerator DoHorizontalSwipeRotate(float degreesRight)
{
    float t = 0;
    Quaternion startRot = transform.rotation;

    // update rotation until 
    while (t < 1f)
    {
        // let next frame occur
        yield return null;

        // update timer
        t = Mathf.Min(1f, t + Time.deltaTime/swipeRotationDuration); 
       
        // Find how much rotation corresponds to time at t:
        float degrees = degreesRight * swipeRotateAnimationCurve.Evaluate(t);

        // Apply that amount of rotation to the starting rotation:
        transform.rotation = startRot * Quaternion.Euler(0f, degrees, 0f);
    }

    // allow for next swipe
    swipeRotateCoroutine = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So When it comes to directions in Unity it is not always what we think it should be I've already answered a question related to this [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438280/what-vector3-i-would-use-here-in-transform-rotate/63439215#63439215) So in your case to rotate an object clock-wise, you need to use `Vector3.forward` instead of `Vector3.down`. This covers defining an axis around witch your object is going to rotate.

Now let's talk about the direction like `rotate to right`/`rotate to left` or `clockwise`/`counter Clockwise`. When you want to rotate your object clockwise you use -ve(imaginative) angle and when you want to rotate your object counter clockwise you use +ve(positive) angle.

So your code should be as follows to rotate your object clockwise:

```
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.forward);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, 0.03f);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP asked

Comment: Now that you are pointing this, I think you are right. And your answer is more appropriate to the question.